# <httpErrors> não funciona

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Estou tentando fazer um tratamento de erros com essa configuração:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
    </modules>

    <httpErrors  errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Erro/404.html" />
    </httpErrors>

  </system.webServer>
```

Minha pagina `404.html` está dentro de `Views/Erro/404.html`.

Mas ao executar uma url que não existe ele não faz o tratamento, vem a pagina de erro padrão do IIS.

Vi vários tutoriais e cada um faz uma coisa diferente, por exemplo:

Usar `subStatusCode='-1'` ou usar `defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL"`

O que no meu caso não funcionou.

Alguém consegue ver alguma coisa errada na configuração?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei o problema:

Falou colocar `<customErrors mode="Off" />` dentro de   `</system.web>`

Não sei explicar exatamente o porque disso, talvez um tratamento trave o outro, mas no meu caso resolveu.

Answer (score 2):

Sim. Algumas.

A configuração correta inicialmente seria assim:

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.web>
  ...
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/Erro/404.html" />
    </customErrors> 
  ...
  </system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

Mas eu particularmente não gosto deste modo porque ele vai contra a arquitetura do MVC. Sou mais a abordagem de usar *Actions* de *Controllers* para produzir telas de erro mais interessantes:

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.web>
  ...
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/BadRequest"/>
    </customErrors>
  ...
  </system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

O problema é que este modo faz com que a transferência retorne um código 302, e logo depois um código 200, o que fere o protocolo HTTP, já que tivemos um erro (ou seja, códigos 400 em diante), então precisamos adaptar de novo.

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.web>
  ...
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/BadRequest"/>
    </customErrors>
  ...
  </system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

Outro problema: isto não funciona direito, porque o ASP.NET MVC usa `Server.Transfer` pra redirecionar para um conteúdo **estático**, não dinâmico. No fim, a configuração ficaria assim:

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.web>
  ...
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Erro/404.html">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/BadRequest"/>
    </customErrors>
  ...
  </system.web>
...
</configuration>
```

Enfim, não gosto muito de nenhuma dessas formas. Prefiro uma outra, [proposta por esta resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026907/1314276):

## Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            Response.Clear();

            var rd = new RouteData();

            rd.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
            rd.Values["action"] = "NotFound";

            IController c = new ErrorsController();
            c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
        }
    }
}
```

## ErrorsController.cs

```
public sealed class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        ActionResult result;

        object model = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            result = View(model);
        else
            result = PartialView("_NotFound", model);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Eu diria que é a forma mais decente de tratar erros HTTP numa aplicação MVC.

Aliás, vale a pena ler a resposta que linkei aqui. Ela explica mais minuciosamente todos os problemas de usar erros HTTP pela configuração.

Comment: Eu optei por colocar dentro de  <system.webServer> para fazer um tratamento mais amplo possível, se colocar dentro de   <system.web> ele é mais limitado. Uma artigo legal que eu li sobre isso é esse, mas não o que ele fez aí não funcionou no meu http://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging